# iOS : Size classes issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, adaptive-ui

I'm creating a UI using size classes. As you can see in the below picture , there's issue with iPhone 6 Plus . Please help iPhone 4s always creates a mess. Do tell me if the UI is correct?

Image description:

[image]

Comment: Plz upload image what exact output you want to achieve?

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic exact as 4-inch iPhone shows in my image. Similar UI for all screens

Comment: what issue you are facing with iPhone 6s screen ?

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic distance between pink button and login merchant is too much in iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting for your app? If it's 9.x, then I would suggest  you use `UIStackView`. Once you're done configuring the  stack, then you would just pin it to the edges and you're done. http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: @AdrianB minimum target is iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!!

**Select Login Merchant button, Blue and Pink button with OR label and put them in Stack View with Vertical axis.** name it as (Bottom StackView)
Put some proper spacing between them.

If your image height is not fixed then make it relative to the device height, that means create a **height constraint of imageView = (1/3)height of mainView.**

Also you can take **Label** and **textField Username** in Horizontal StackView then combine both **textFiled** (username and pass) and **Label** in **Vertical StackView.**

Make vertical constraints **Greater Than Equal to 20** between Bottom StackView and Center StackView.

this will give to better result in all screens.

In Case if you don't use **StackView** then,

Combine Bottom 3 button in SingleView (**BottomView**) and Upper textFields and Labels in SingleView (**CenterView**).

Then set vertical spacing s **Greater Than Equal to 20** between them.

Make your image height as relative to screen size as described above.

Comment: hi the problem is minimum iOS is 7, StackView is available after iOS 9 if im not wrong.

Comment: Is it ok, if i put all the controls in an individual views? i mean top, center, bottom view.

Comment: Yes, Its totally fine. Make sure top container sticks to top and Bottom sticks to bottom. Then Center sticks to your top containers bottom end. Your spacing between center and Bottom container is flexible.